# Change style if checkbox checked

Tags: jquery

How can I do that ? This is not working, no results, no effect, no error output.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
    {
            if($(this).attr("checked") === true){
            $('.hoverbox .a').css('text-transform', 'uppercase');
            }
            else
            {
            $('.hoverbox .a').css('text-transform', 'lowercase');
            }
    });
```

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do NOT completely change your original question on an edit. Submit a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: I didn't, its the same problem.

Comment: It is not the same problem. Your original source code didn't have an `.on('change', ...)` in it. Worse, you've added the completely useless statement "it won't work" without explaining what "it" is or what "working" looks like.

Comment: I can't uderstand why it is so hard to figure it out what I pretend to achieve. If checked checkbox then uppercase that div class else lower case it.

Comment: It's hard to figure it out because you never explained it in the question. Thank you for finally clarifying; I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need an event handler:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(e) {
   // do stuff
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on

Or possibly (it's hard for me to understand your intentions) you need to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of `.attr()`:

```
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    // do something 
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

**update:** Putting it all together:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(e) {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('.hoverbox .a').css('text-transform', 'uppercase');
    } else {
        $('.hoverbox .a').css('text-transform', 'lowercase');
    };
});
```

Although adding a custom class and [toggling it](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) would save you a little trouble:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(e) {
    $('.hoverbox .a').toggleClass('uppercase');
});
```

CSS:

```
.hoverbox .a {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
.hoverbox .a.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I *think* his question is more about changing the style, not handling the event.

Comment: @BenM Nope, still not unambiguous.

Comment: I agree. Hence why my initial comment said that I **think**!

Comment: @Blazemonger I had my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562875/script-not-working-properly-after-partial-postback. can you please help me to solve it....

Answer (score 2):

Why cant you use CSS? Why waste javascript?

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```